# Swift let computed property to Objective C syntax

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have this code in a Swift application and was curious of what its equivalent syntax would be in Objective C

```
typealias Signal = (Float) -> (Float)

static let sine: Signal = { (time: Float) -> Float in
    return amplitude * sin(2.0 * Float.pi * frequency * time)
}
```

I believe I would declare `Signal` as follows:

```
typedef float (^Signal)(float);
```

but I am not sure how I would setup a similar way of setting up the syntax to retrieve the value. I thought about a class method but the didn't quite work out.

Thank you

Comment: So you are asking [how to write a block](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/)?

Comment: I have looked at that and I am just missing something. I have written blocks before, but never where it can be used like the computed variable is. Im sorry Im just blanking on this. 

Its eventually being used like the following

  private var signal: Signal

   setWave(Oscillator.sine)

    func setWave(_ signal: @escaping Signal) {
        self.signal = signal
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a computed property. This is a “[closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)”.

So this defines a type alias for a closure that takes a `Float` as a parameter and returns a `Float`:

```
typealias Signal = (Float) -> (Float)
```

You can create an instance of this `Signal` closure like so:

```
let doubler: Signal = { $0 * 2 }
```

And you can call that closure like so:

```
print(doubler(21))     // 42
```

---

The equivalent Objective-C syntax to define the type for a “[block](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW1)”:

```
typedef float (^Signal)(float);
```

To create an instance of a `Signal` block:

```
Signal doubler = ^(float input) {
    return input * 2;
};
```

And to call it:

```
NSLog(@"%f", doubler(21));   // 42
```

Comment: Thank you again Rob, I was going in circles between the two and was going blank.